# Apache - File does not exist error (file is definitely there) - favicon.ico

Tags: apache, lamp

I have apache set up as a LAMP server in Linux

In the root /www/ directory, I have a favicon.ico but it never shows in the browser (Chromium, Firefox) and in the apache error.log I get the following error:

```
[Mon Jul 08 17:32:30 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico
```

I'm not especially bothered with the file not appearing but it is there and I haven't been able to figure out why it's giving me this error.

Comment: Is the 'root /www directory' inside your site's Document root (or at least aliased into it)? What's the URL for the failed request in the access_log?

Comment: I hate to say it but... most likely it's not there (or rather, there's a file there that has an ever so slightly different name... look out for whitespace characters & the like).

Comment: Thanks for the comments Marc & Wrikken, I found out the issue after changing the resolution of the favicon.ico file as per the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Answered in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> The favicon was 32x32 which seems to be why. I substituted with a 16x16 favicon.ico file and I no longer get this error.
>
> What I further don't understand is why I would get this at all - presumably some setting as I have an apache server on a hosted website with the same 32x32 favicon but it appears there and there are no errors.